# Too many parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

Ok, i have managed to end at this one.

**Controller:**

```
  $addProperty=Property::addProperty($title,$description,$location,
                 $agent,$owner,$lat,$long,$position,$photoHolder,
                 $stars,$negatives,$adverts,$dropLink,$photosSite);
```

**Model:**

```
  public static function addProperty($title,$description,$location,$agent,
           $owner,$lat,$long,$position,
           $photoHolder,$stars,$negatives,
           $adverts,$dropLink,$photosSite)
```

The problem is that, not only, i have too many parameters but i need to pass around 10 more.

Any advice?

Comment: Pass an array or object.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the most appropriate way!

Comment: Also, I don't know the use/design but `addProperty()` seems like it should add ONE: `function addProperty($property,$value)` and maybe `function addProperties($propArray)` or something for multiple.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, `addProperty()` adds one row to the table `properties` alongside with its many to many relations on the middle tables. Is that wrong?

Comment: It's only wrong if it doesn't work. However, could a programmer stepping into your role figure out what's going on there in under a minute?

Comment: @castis Yes its pretty easy to understand whats happening as my classes are separated correctly. The only difficulty, is the question i have posted because of the number of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few ways you could do this. My preferred way though when working with models is to have a set method for each attribute. That way you don't need to pass everything all at once (very useful as an application evolves and stuff gets added/removed).

So in a model, I would usually have something like this:

```
class Property {

    private $title;
    private $description;
    private $location;

    /**
     * Creates an instance of property via a static method.
     *
     */
    public static factory()
    {
        return new Property();
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
        return $this;
    }

    // because the attributes in this instance are private I would also need getters

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $title;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $description;
    }

    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $location;
    }
}
```

Then you can also add in a `save()` method or whatever else you want it to do.

OK, so I've added a new static method called `factory` which allows you to create an instance without having to assign it to a variable. In addition to that I have added `return $this;` to all methods which do not return an attribute.

What this effectively means is you can now do this:

```
// create a new property
Property::factory()
    ->setTitle($title)
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setLocation($location)
    ->save(); // if you had that function
```

The beauty of this is that if you did need to have a break in it, then the following would also work.

```
// create a new property
$property = Property::factory()
    ->setTitle($title)
    ->setDescription($description); // this is returning the property instance `return $this`

// do some processing to get the $location value

// continue creating the new property
$property
    ->setLocation($location)
    ->save(); // if you had that function
```

Comment: Nice answer! I use `static function` in order to call the model without create an instance. I'm a a newbie in `object oriented php` so can you please explain why is better to do it without static functions?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what I'd have in an application. Static functions are good for doing one off things, or having as helper functions. But when you work with models you usually want to hang onto them for a while, so you can perform various actions on them. In your case you wanted to add more attributes, which meant you had to pump more variables into the static function, thus making it bloated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I can understand everything except the usage of get() functions. For what reason are there?

Comment: Because I've defined the variables as private it means they're only available within the scope of the class, so you wouldn't be able to call them externally. By adding the get methods you would be able to get an attribute like so `$property->getTitle();`. By limiting access to the variables and enforcing the use of setters and getters it adds a thin layer of developer protection, because you're more implicitly aware of when you're getting/setting those attributes.

Comment: Ok, i figured out now! Excellent answer and excellent explanation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

better way is to pass parameter as an array :

```
$params=array(
'title'=>'title',
'other_parameter'=>'value',
);

$addProperty=Property::addProperty($params);
```